# Should I query the ref: urls in the ldapsearch output?

Tags: openldap

When doing an ldapsearch from a script, I will get some lines with

```
# search reference
ref: ldap://<url>/<baseDn>
```

Am I supposed to do the same query to these servers or just stick with the values returned from the original query?

If I do an ldapsearch and receive a status code of 10, then that is a referral and I would definitely follow that.

Comment: If you're using Java and JNDI you can make it follow the references atuomatically.

Comment: What is the right thing to do?  What is the value of following the references if I have an entry already?